# How to disable bold button in CKEDITOR

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have multiple instances of ckeditor on one page. When var x is true I want to disable bold button. When x is false I want to keep it enabled.

Let's say I have 4 instances:

- instance1: bold enabled
- instance2: bold enabled
- instance3: bold **disabled**
- instance4: bold enabled

I was trying to hide bold button on ckeditor instanceReady with CSS but couldn't succeed as I always hide wrong elements etc.

I wonder if any of you was working on similar problem?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use config option to remove buttons.
Here you have example how it works:
https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/OxZBoM

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', {
  removeButtons: 'Bold'
} );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor3' );
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor4' );
```

And here link to documentation about buttons hiding:
https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeButtons

Answer (score 1):

Create a CSS class:

```
.hide_cke_button {
    display: none !important;
}
```

And then with jQuery:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor3.on('instanceReady', function(evt) {
    if (x) {
        $('#cke_editor3').find('.cke_button__bold').addClass('hide_cke_button');
    }
});
```